# Updated dataframe - keep the last update - dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains the following values :

```
In[17]: df
Out[17]: 
         maj       date  value
0 2006-01-19 2006-01-22   0.95
1 2006-01-20 2006-01-22   0.03
2 2006-01-21 2006-01-22   0.28
3 2006-01-22 2006-01-22   0.98
5 2006-01-20 2006-01-23   0.14
6 2006-01-21 2006-01-23   0.04
7 2006-01-22 2006-01-23   0.10
8 2006-01-23 2006-01-23   0.13
9 2006-01-24 2006-01-23   0.13
```

I want to obtain by a function the last update of each date (here 2006-01-24 for 2006-01-23 and 2006-01-22 for 2006-01-22). We doesn't know in advance the number of days which separe the date from the maj, but we need to have the last maj for each date) :

```
In[17]: df
Out[17]: 
         maj       date  value
3 2006-01-22 2006-01-22   0.98
9 2006-01-24 2006-01-23   0.13
```

Someone have an idea on how to perform it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates) and pass param `subset=['date']` so it looks for duplicates using that column and `take_last=True` to keep just the latest row:

```
In [357]:
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['date'], take_last=True)

Out[357]:
          maj        date  value
3  2006-01-22  2006-01-22   0.98
9  2006-01-24  2006-01-23   0.13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.reset_index().sql().max("maj","","over(partition by date) max2","*")\
    .filter("maj=max2").select("date,maj,value,")
    
    ┌────────────┬────────────┬─────────┐
    │    date    │    maj     │  value  │
    │  varchar   │  varchar   │ varchar │
    ├────────────┼────────────┼─────────┤
    │ 2006-01-22 │ 2006-01-22 │ 0.98    │
    │ 2006-01-23 │ 2006-01-24 │ 0.13    │
    └────────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
```